# « Fuir » vs « enfuir » vs « s'enfuir »

Tags: vocabulaire

Je me suis référé aux dictionnaires et à d'autres ressources. Par exemple, [cette question](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=543574) sur [Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/enfuir) allègue « *there's no major difference between fuire and s'enfuire in this context* ».

Pas seulement « in this context », quelles sont les différences entre *fuir*, *enfuir* et *s'enfuir* ?

Comment: A ne pas confondre avec les verbes *fouir / enfouir / s'enfouir*

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: En vue de vos réversions, où dois-je poser les demandes de précision ? Je veux éviter de le faire en tant que commentaire car il y est impossible de composer et ainsi sera difficile de lire.

Comment: Pour des questions qui n'ont rien à voir avec la question de départ, parce que tu ne comprends pas certains détails d'une réponse, tu as deux solutions : (1) demander des précisions en commentaire, (2) poser une nouvelle question dans un post séparé. Stack Exchange n'est pas conçu pour une discussion à coup d'édits.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a des différences majeures **dans la syntaxe** que ces deux verbes permettent, mais  il est vrai que dans la question à laquelle tu lies, les deux s'emploie indifféremment que ce soit du point de vue de la syntaxe ou de la sémantique: en effet, il n'y a pas grand différence de sens entre les deux verbes.

Les principales différences de constructions sont:

- Seul *fuir* s'emploie de manière transitive. L'objet grammatical est un objet, une personne ou un lieu que l'on cherche à éviter, ou dont on s'éloigne.
- Le seul complément qui peut accompagner *s'enfuir* est un complément circonstanciel.
- Le lieu dont on s'enfuit doit être exprimé avec la préposition *de* quand on emploie *s'enfuir*.

ETA: Quand je parle de différence de sens, je parle du sens "prendre la fuite". *Fuir* a également le sens métonymique de "avoir une fuite", comme le fait remarquer Lamine. On est techniquement encore dans le même domaine sémantique, mais avec une relation syntaxique inversée entre l'agent et le contenant.

Comment: (+1) Réponse bien faite pour la distinction entre *fuir* et *s'enfuir*. Ajoutons simplement qu'utiliser *enfuir* tout seul n'est pas possible.

Comment: Je ne vois pas la question en question, donc je ne sais pas de quel contexte vous parlez. Mais il faut signaler que ces deux verbes peuvent avoir un sens complètement différent. Un robinet fuit, mais il ne s'enfuit pas.

Comment: @Lamine C'est vrai, j'ai oublié de mentionner ce sens ("avoir une fuite"), qui est dissimulé dans l'entrée de Fuir du *Trésor* informatisé